# Gradle fails to get CODEBUILD_SRC_DIR_source1 variable from AWS CodePipeline

Tags: gradle, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild, aws-codecommit

I am trying to use multiple CodeCommit sources in my CodePipeline build. I defined a secondary source pointing to a project in CodeCommit in CodeBuild and assigned it "sec_proj" identifier. In my main project I have a Gradle build which has the following code

```
    copy {
        from System.getProperty("CODEBUILD_SRC_DIR_sec_proj", CODEBUILD_SRC_DIR_sec_proj)
        into "$buildDir/sec_proj"
    }
```

When I define `CODEBUILD_SRC_DIR_sec_proj` in my local environment everything runs as expected, files from the 2nd project are copied and build completes. However when I attempt to run it in my pipeline I get the following error:

```
17:50:26.092 [ERROR] 
[org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Caused by: 
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: Could not get unknown property 
'CODEBUILD_SRC_DIR_sec_proj' for object of type 
org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.CopySpecWrapper_Decorated.
```

So obviously my gradle process does not have this variable available.
I tried to force it using the following syntax in my `buildspec.yml`

```
phases:
  build:
    commands:
      - ./gradlew -i -d -S build -DCODEBUILD_SRC_DIR_sec_proj=$CODEBUILD_SRC_DIR_sec_proj
```

And it failed with same message. And since according to the documentation

> Your primary source is defined under the source attribute. All other
>   sources are called secondary sources and appear under
>   secondarySources. All secondary sources are installed in their own
>   directory. This directory is stored in the built-in environment
>   variable CODEBUILD_SRC_DIR_sourceIdentifer.

it looks like I'm missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the solution. Turns out `CODEBUILD_SRC_DIR_sec_proj` is there but `System.getProperty("CODEBUILD_SRC_DIR_sec_proj", CODEBUILD_SRC_DIR_sec_proj)` will not get it. But `System.getProperties().getProperty("CODEBUILD_SRC_DIR_sec_proj")` will. Then it works like a charm

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code:

`System.getProperty("CODEBUILD_SRC_DIR_sec_proj", CODEBUILD_SRC_DIR_sec_proj)`

and the signature of the method:

[`System.getProperty(String key, String defaultValue)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getProperty(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))

I think the error message is actually returning to the variable `CODEBUILD_SRC_DIR_sec_proj` which might not be defined. (Maybe you've defined it elsewhere, I'm not sure)

I would recommend simply:

```
copy {
    from System.getProperty("CODEBUILD_SRC_DIR_sec_proj")
    into "$buildDir/sec_proj"
}
```

Comment: That's the strangeness of it. Your call will not work but the one I stated in my answer will

Comment: @Bostone you mean `System.getProperty("CODEBUILD_SRC_DIR_sec_proj")` doesn't work? or `System.getProperty("CODEBUILD_SRC_DIR_sec_proj", CODEBUILD_SRC_DIR_sec_proj)` doesn't work?